# Pushing UITabBarController in UISplitViewController Detail - Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController setup, working perfectly well in iPad, however issue on iPhone.

Master hierarchy: `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UITableViewController`

Detail hierarchy: `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UITableViewController`

I select a tableview item in the master and it pushes the detail tabbarcontroller, however it results in have two navigation bars.

The original master nav bar, then below the detail nav bar. I understand that as I am not pushing a `UINavigationController` it won't automatically replace the nav bar.

So how can I resolve this?